# From an XML String to a dynamic "LIST" Output

Tags: javascript, java, xml, groovy

Good afternoon,
I'm looking for tips on this one. Finally, I'm getting close to the output I desire.

```
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper

String XML = '''
    <results>
  <result>
    <Firstname>Marco</Firstname>
    <Surname>Alves</Surname>
    <Age>33</Age>
    <Address>Lisbon</Address>
    <ALIAS>Valentino Rossi</ALIAS>
  </result>
  <result>
    <Firstname>André</Firstname>
    <Surname>Vieira</Surname>
    <Age>31</Age>
    <Address>Lisbon</Address>
  </result>
  <result>
    <FirstName>Pedro</FirstName>
    <Surname>Kuclo</Surname>
  </result>
  <result>
    <Address>Lisbon</Address>
    <Surname>Kuclo</Surname>
  </result>
</results>
'''
         
def people = new XmlSlurper().parseText(XML)
people.result.findAll { m ->
    m.Firstname.toString().contains("Marco")
}.each { m ->
    println(m)
}
```

This is the current OUTPUT:

```
MarcoAlves33LisbonValentino Rossi
```

Anyone have an idea to achieve this output?

```
List { "Marco", "Alves", "33", "Lisbon", "Valentino Rossi }
```

The output must be dynamic, let's say, without define the "{m.Firstname} \n${m.Surname}"

What I tried so far:

```
// println("\n${m.Firstname} \n${m.Surname} \n${m.Address} \n${m.age}\n${m.ALIAS}")
```

But this way I have to define the output and I want it to dynamic.

Comment: Do you want to output JSON? Or is `List` part of the output?

Comment: Hello, my dear @cfrick 
JSON will work pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to return a List containing specific properties or properties in a different order, you can use the collect method to collect the elements for each matching entry however you see fit and return that as a List:

```
String XML = '''
    <results>
  <result>
    <Firstname>Marco</Firstname>
    <Surname>Alves</Surname>
    <Age>33</Age>
    <Address>Lisbon</Address>
    <ALIAS>Valentino Rossi</ALIAS>
  </result>
  <result>
    <Firstname>André</Firstname>
    <Surname>Vieira</Surname>
    <Age>31</Age>
    <Address>Lisbon</Address>
  </result>
  <result>
    <FirstName>Pedro</FirstName>
    <Surname>Kuclo</Surname>
  </result>
  <result>
    <Address>Lisbon</Address>
    <Surname>Kuclo</Surname>
  </result>  
</results>
'''

def people = new XmlSlurper().parseText(XML)
def results = people.result.findAll { m ->
    m.Firstname.toString().contains("Marco")
}.collect{ it ->
   [it.Firstname, it.Surname, it.Age, it.Address, it.ALIAS]
}

println results
```

Which generates the output:

> [[Marco, Alves, 33, Lisbon, Valentino Rossi]]

You can easily modify what is collected to achieve the results you want.

If what you want is to take the matching results and convert each result, including all properties of the result to Json, you can instead do this:

```
def people = new XmlSlurper().parseText(XML)
def results = people.result.findAll { person ->
    person.Firstname.toString().contains("Marco")
}.collect{ result -> result.children().collectEntries{ child -> [(child.name()) , child.text()]} }

results = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(results)
println results
```

Which will yield these results:

```
[
  {
    "Firstname":"Marco",
    "Surname":"Alves",
    "Age":"33",
    "Address":"Lisbon",
    "ALIAS":"Valentino Rossi"
  }
]
```

Comment: So it's not that you want the order in a specific way, just all fields for each result with a matching name to be added to the result in a List?

Comment: Hello! @pczeus 
`
[
  {
    "Firstname":"Marco",
    "Surname":"Alves",
    "Age":"33",
    "Address":"Lisbon",
    "ALIAS":"Valentino Rossi"
  }
]
`


You can modify the output to be:
`
[
  {
    "Marco",
    "Alves",
    "33",
    "Lisbon",
    "Valentino Rossi"
  }
]
`
Is it possible? Thank you in advance :

Comment: What you are asking for is no longer JSON, which should be in the name:value pair format. Now what you are asking for is juat a List of Lists where each nested List contains the Strings of values. Either way you can slightly modifiy the above code as you see fit to accomplish that easily.

Comment: I managed to achive the result. But your help was everything, tomorrow i'll show you the code. Thank you a lot buddy! @pczeus

Comment: Hello @pczeus 

`  }.collect {
        result -> result.children().collectMany {
            child -> [child.text()]
        }
    } //This will collect only the child names, to get the child text like "Firstname": Marco - Use: child.name(). Both arguments can be used.

    println(results)`

I just added a small change and it's working! Thank you